# If field is empty populate with the value from another field

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to achieve this scenario:

I have two fields `Field1` and `Field2`. `Field1` is missing values and I want to write the query when the value from `Field1` is missing to get populated with the value from `Field2`.

I've tried to look up online but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a CASE statement to check if the field is empty, and select an alternative field as a fallback:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Field1 IS NULL 
    THEN Field2 
    ELSE Field1 
END AS yourField 
FROM SomeRandomTable
```